# Create a copy and not a reference of a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, copy

I'm currently working on a Python program that involves using NumPy for image processing. However, I've encountered an issue when trying to create a **deep copy** of a NumPy array instead of just copying the reference.

Here's a snippet of my code, where I read in a PNG image and assign it to `imageOriginal_3d`:

```
width, height, pngData, metaData = png.Reader(file).asDirect()
planeCount = metaData['planes']
print('Image Size: ' + str(width) + 'x' + str(height) + ' Pixel')
image_2d = np.vstack(list(map(np.uint8, pngData)))
imageOriginal_3d = np.reshape(image_2d, (width, height, planeCount)) 
imageEdited_3d = imageOriginal_3d // TODO: CREATE DEEP COPY
```

My intention is to edit `imageEdited_3d` without affecting the values in `imageOriginal_3d`. However, when I modify `imageEdited_3d`, the changes currently also appear in `imageOriginal_3d`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to create the copy of the object. You may do it using [`numpy.copy()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) since you are having `numpy` object. Hence, your initialisation should be like:

```
imageEdited_3d = imageOriginal_3d.copy()
```

Also there is [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module for creating the *deep copy* OR, *shallow copy*. This works independent of object type. For example, your code using `copy` should be as:

```
from copy import copy, deepcopy

# Creates shallow copy of object
imageEdited_3d = copy(imageOriginal_3d)

# Creates deep copy of object
imageEdited_3d = deepcopy(imageOriginal_3d)
```

*Description:*

> A **shallow copy** constructs a new compound object and then (to the
>   extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
>   the original.
>
> A **deep copy** constructs a new compound object and then, recursively,
>   inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

Comment: Is there a notable difference in time consumption when constructing a deep copy versus shallow copy?

Comment: @wedran There is indeed. Deepcopy is much more time consuming! Try [this gist](https://gist.github.com/we-taper/6a3e933fe2ff434c7bc313f51a07f1a4)