# Why matrix elements change according to previous lines in python numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a reproducible example:

```
np.random.seed(123)
a = np.random.randn(9)
a = np.reshape(a, (3,3))
b = a
b[0,0] = 1
```

In the above code when I change `b[0,0]` element in matrix b ( for example `b[0,0]=1` in the last line), `a[0,0]` also change to `a[0,0]=1` based on `b=a` line. Whats wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python numpy create copy and not reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196995/python-numpy-create-copy-and-not-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b = a` assigns the variable `b` to the same contents as `a`. This does not create a copy of the array, `b` is merely an alias. Accessing `b[0,0]` is equivalent to accessing `a[0,0]`. If you want a copy of the array, then try this:

```
np.random.seed(123)
a = np.random.randn(9)
a = np.reshape(a, (3,3))
b = a.copy()
b[0,0] = 1
```