# How to make a variable equivalent a different variable

Tags: python, numpy

I have code like this:

```
import numpy as np

area = np.zeros([2,2])
f = area
print(area)
f[0][0]=1
print(area)
print(f)
```

Which produces the following arrays

```
[[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]

[[1. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]

[[1. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
```

How do I get it so that the `area` array is not 'linked' to the `f` array i.e. after the calculation the `f` array changes but the `area` array does not?

Comment: These aren't two arrays that are "linked", **it is the same array**. `x = y` says "let the name `x` now refer to the object currently being referenced by the name `y`", it doesn't say, "copy the object being referred to by `y` and assign it to the name `x`"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python numpy create copy and not reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196995/python-numpy-create-copy-and-not-reference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make a copy of `area`:

```
f = area.copy()
```

Answer (score 2):

They're not just "linked"; they are 2 names for *the same array*.

If you want them to be distinct, make a *copy* of `area` to assign to `f`.

Answer (score 1):

You should copy your first array:

`f = area.copy()`

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent this by making a copy:

1.

```
A=B
```

Assignment of list is happened , so that's why change in one place creates change another list.

2.

```
B[:] = A
```

This only works if B is already existing.

3.

```
B = A.copy()
```

Both 2 and 3 copies the list into another but they don't get linked to each other.

Comment: which one? A.copy()?

Comment: The OP is working with a numpy array, not a list, as you have written in your question

Comment: Yes but you are using the word list in you answer, that is what I'm saying, and the op is a out numpy arrays