# Smoothing of a polygon

Tags: python, loops, class, polygon, smoothing

I was wondering whether anyone could help me with what I was doing wrong in this code?

I am very new to coding so simple solutions using the same logical coding would be greatly appreciated.

The first picture is the description of what I need to do.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
def smooth_polygon(self, alpha):

        n = len(self.x)
        self.x[0] = (1-alpha)*self.x[0]+alpha*1/2*(self.x[-1] + self.x[1])

        self.y[0] = (1-alpha)*self.y[0]+alpha*1/2*(self.y[-1] + self.y[1])
        
        self.x[-1] = (1-alpha)*self.x[-1]+alpha*1/2*(self.x[-2] + self.x[0])
        
        self.y[-1] = (1-alpha) * self.y[-1] + alpha * 1/2 * (self.y[-2] + self.y[0])
        
        for i in range(1, n-1):
            self.x[i] = (1-alpha)*self.x[i]+1/2*alpha*(self.x[i-1] + self.x[i+1])
            self.y[i] = (1-alpha)*self.y[i]+1/2*alpha*(self.y[i-1] + self.y[i+1])
    

        plt.plot(self.x,self.y, 'k.-')
        plt.show()
        return self.x,self.y
```

The 3rd picture is the plot of the red polygon, which is the CORRECT smoothed polygon:

[image]

The last is my figure:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your formulae for the "new" values involve only the "old" values. So these variables need to be distinct: you can overwrite the older ones later. However, your code is updating in place, so some of the variables are being updated with "new" values, not old.

Comment: So would a solution be to make a new array, where I take all the values from and only update the "self" with the old values?

Comment: Yes, I would make a new array. Update to new values from the existing ones. Then copy back to the array in your class.

Comment: For some reason now it doesn't even plot a new polygon. Did I do it wrong? sorry for the confusion...

https://ibb.co/RPpLzXX

Comment: Would it help doing it the other way around? So I update the class with the new array? was that what you meant?

Comment: Please never post/link to images of code, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question. About your question: you didn't make a copy of the original data, you just added other names for it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196995/create-a-copy-and-not-a-reference-of-a-numpy-array to make an actual copy of the original data.

Comment: Yes, I think Thierry Lathuille's statement is correct. Python's (as opposed to C, C++, Fortran etc) use of = often yields multiple names for the same object, rather than making a copy. For the latter use the .copy() method on numpy arrays. It would help if you gave complete, runnable code; it's difficult to test and debug otherwise.

Comment: Oh I am very sorry.
How do I post my code in this segment then? its too many letters it says...

Comment: You need a minimum reproducible example - not 1000+ lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, modifying your arrays element by element is the source of your problems. You could make a new temporary array and then move in place (or do it all in one list comprehension). In addition, a pattern that I would favor is that of *immutable objects*: smoothing a `Polygon` returns a *new* `Polygon`, and leaves the original unchanged.

Here is that approach:

```py
class Polygon:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = list(x)  # x and y could be an iterable, a numpy array, ...
        self.y = list(y)
        assert len(self.x) == len(self.y), "x and y must have same length"

    @staticmethod
    def smooth_filter(a, alpha):
        roll_neg = a[-1:] + a[:-1]
        roll_pos = a[1:] + a[:1]
        return [
            (1 - alpha) * u + alpha/2 * (v + w)
            for u, v, w in zip(a, roll_neg, roll_pos)
        ]

    def smoothed(self, alpha=0.1):
        '''returns a new, smoothed Polygon'''
        return Polygon(
            Polygon.smooth_filter(self.x, alpha),
            Polygon.smooth_filter(self.y, alpha),
        )

    def plot(self, ax=None, **kwargs):
        ax = plt.gca() if ax is None else ax
        ax.plot(self.x + self.x[:1], self.y + self.y[:1], **kwargs)
        return ax
```

Now, an example use:

```py
# rough approximation of the points in the OP's image
p = Polygon(
    [0, 11, 18, 28, 46, 36, 39, 23, 5, 8],
    [4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 8, 16, 12, 16, 12],
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 4))
p.plot(c='k', ax=ax)
p.smoothed(.5).plot(c='r', ax=ax)
```

[image]

The following would be harder to do if the smoothing was an in-place modification:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 4))
p.plot(c='k', ax=ax)
for r in range(10):
    alpha = (r + 1)/10
    p.smoothed(alpha).plot(c='r', alpha=1 - alpha, ax=ax)
```

[image]